# How do I use multiple source paths with dokka's fatjar?

Tags: kotlin-dokka

I'm using dokka to generate some code for a multi-module project.  I have successfully been able to generate documentation for a single module with their cli fatjar, but the module is dependent on another one.

Let me note that the only difference between the processes' commands I kick off are the sources argument (though I have redacted things like the classpath for ease and NDA purposes):

### Single module

*(working)*

`java -jar <path_to_jar>/dokka-fatjar-0.9.17.jar /<absolute_path1>/src -output docs -classpath <class_path>`

### Multiple sources

*(not even analyzing and produces 0 results in output directory)*

`java -jar <path_to_jar>/dokka-fatjar-0.9.17.jar /<absolute_path1>/src:/<absolute_path2>/src -output docs -classpath <class_path>`

The classpaths end up being the exact same (after aggregating them in the project build code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working for me was
`java -jar <path_to_jar>/dokka-fatjar-0.9.17.jar -src /<absolute_path1>/src:/<absolute_path2>/src -output docs -classpath <class_path>'=`

That is, using `-src` with the native path separator.  Provided by @Semoro at dokka's gh issues.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Separate source directories with space, not with `:`

`java -jar <path_to_jar>/dokka-fatjar-0.9.17.jar /<absolute_path1>/src /<absolute_path2>/src -output docs -classpath <class_path>`

This will produce single documentation with mixed sources from both directories.

To produce separated documentation for each of module, use

`java -jar <path_to_jar>/dokka-fatjar-0.9.17.jar /<absolute_path1>/src -output docs -classpath <class_path_for_module1> -module module1`

And then for module2, which depends on module1:

`java -jar <path_to_jar>/dokka-fatjar-0.9.17.jar /<absolute_path2>/src -output docs -classpath <class_path_for_module2> -module module2 -links <deploy_url>^file://./docs/module1/package-list`

Assume that `<class_path_for_module2>` contains compile output of module1 + `<class_path_for_module1>`

Comment: Std output seems to be fine till it gets `Analysing sources and libraries...`

```
Analysing sources and libraries... 
ERROR: error: source file or directory not found: /path1/src /path2/src
```

Seems like it is trying to treat this as one path.  Neither paths have any whitespace in them.